# Tell search engines about a mass htaccess rename

Tags: php, htaccess

I used `htaccess` to redirect my `a.php?x=aaa&y=bbb` to `/subdir/aaa-bbb.htm`. However, after fixing some errors I needed to change that rule to redirect `a.php?x=aaa&y=bbb` to `/subdir/aaa-bbb.htm/100`.

How can I tell search engines that all `htm` files in `/subdir/` have changed to `/subdir/*.htm/100`?

Comment: You hit the low quality filter because you chose to not use any capital letters or proper sentences.

Comment: There's no Central Web Search Engine Authority, you have to use the tools made publicly available by each of the major search engines to request they recrawl your site (requests they'll ignore if you request it too often btw).

Comment: 301 redirects are the only way to inform mass changes in URL structure common for all search engines and people as well.

Answer (score 2):

Set up an htaccess rule from `/subdir/*.htm` to `/subdir/*.htm/100` and wait for the search engines to recrawl you.

Comment: Do not forget to use a 301 redirect, to tell the SE that this is a permanent change.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I would check out is [Google webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).  It is more an observational tool than a configuring tool, but that's ideal because you can configure your site and then check that google reads it well in various ways, and if google does, the other search engines are likely to as well.